# SQLite count members in a group

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

Hey im having problems counting members of a group. The query i have right now returns one row for each group a given user is part of. But i want the amount of members to show up aswell. The three tables im using looks like this:

[image]

Here is the query im working with:
Look in edit!

If i leave out the COUNT part of the code, i receive the 2 groups im expecting. But when i add in the COUNT it only returns one group with members = 2. So it seems like it counts, but im not sure it's the correct answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like you're missing a group by clause

Comment: I tried GROUP BY gp.group_id_foreign. Which returns the two groups, but each with a member count 1, which is not the correct result

Comment: I imagine you'd want to group by g.something. If you're still struggling post up proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT

Comment: I have edited my answer with sqlfiddle and the a more simple sql sample.

Comment: So, if I've got this right, you're after the total number of participants within each group with which user 1 is affiliated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're after the total number of participants within each group with which user 1 is affiliated...

```
SELECT gu1.group_id_foreign
     , COUNT(*) ttl 
  FROM group_participants gu1
  JOIN group_participants gu2
    ON gu2.group_id_foreign = gu1.group_id_foreign
 WHERE gu1.user_id_foreign = 1
 GROUP 
    BY gu1.group_id_foreign;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/821ad/1

Incidentally, the _id column in the group_participants table appears to serve no purpose, and, to my way of thinking, you're naming convention is demented! ;-)

Comment: The _id is only there to act as primary key. I dont even know if i have to use it, but yea. It wont hurt to have it :) And thanks. The code you posted works!

Comment: You already have a perfectly adequate natural key. You should set that as PRIAMRY. ;-)

Comment: Hmm neither user_id_foreign or group_id_foreign are unique as you can see in the fiddle so this wont work. I need the _id

Comment: Neither is individually, but both ARE together.